# Understanding steps taken for summation expression.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Can someone help me understand what steps where taken to bring the left hand side equal to the right hand side?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^c_{n=0} \frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!} + \frac{c^c\rho^{c+1}}{c!(1-\rho)} =&\ \sum^{c-1}_{n=0} \frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+ \frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}+ \frac{c^c\rho^{c+1}}{c!(1-\rho)} \\
 =&\ \sum^{c-1}_{n=0} \frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+ \frac{c^c\rho^c(1-\rho)}{c!(1-\rho)}+ \frac{c^c\rho^{c}\rho}{c!(1-\rho)} \\
 =&\ \sum^{c-1}_{n=0} \frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+ \frac{c^c\rho^c}{c!(1-\rho)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the last term of the sum off, and add it separately:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^c\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+\frac{c^c\rho^{c+1}}{c!(1-\rho)}&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{c-1}\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}\right)+\frac{c^c\rho^{c+1}}{c!(1-\rho)}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{c-1}\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+\frac{(c\rho)^c(1-\rho)+c^c\rho^{c+1}}{c!(1-\rho)}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{c-1}\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}+\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!(1-\rho)}.
\end{align}